# 2 user in MySQL, hosts = "%" and '" (empty)

Tags: mysql

**What distinguishes a user in MySQL?**

1st user:

```
CREATE USER 'user5'@'';
SET PASSWORD FOR 'user5'@'' = PASSWORD('123457');
```

2nd user:

```
CREATE USER 'user5'@'%';
SET PASSWORD FOR 'user5'@'%' = PASSWORD('123456');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'user5'@''  and   'user5'@'%' is the same.
but the user with the host =% has a higher priority to the user with a host =''.

Answer (score 3):

The part after `@` specifies a host from which the user being created is allowed to connect. For example, for web applications where Web-server and MySQL server live on the same physical machine, this parameter usually set to `localhost`. `%` means all hosts, saying that user is allowed to connect from any machine.

Although `username@hostname1` and `username@hostname2` use same username, they are *different* users and can have different privileges.

Comment: Super helpful answer! You say `%` means all hosts. If, however, the host is left empty (like in the asker's example), what does that imply about who is allowed to connect?